# Do structured light camera sensors work outdoors?

Tags: kinect, cameras

Do structured light camera sensors like the structure.io, Intel RealSense or Microsoft Kinect work outdoors?

I read these sensors wont work outdoors because of ambient IR light. Can someone provide this with proper references/tests? I mean what degree of IR illumination is needed for the sensor to stop working etc.

There are videos on YouTube that show Microsoft Kinect working outdoors:

- [Prairie Dog II: UGV Kinect Sensor Outside](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9e4lYzTK6Mo) - limited outdoors range
- [Outdoor Kinect Data Collection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rI6CU9aRDIo) - heavy interference with direct sunlight

However, the (not yet released) new [Intel RealSence R200 specification](https://software.intel.com/en-us/realsense/devkit) says "range up to 3-4 meters indoors, longer range outdoors" while the older F200 says "0.2 meters - 1.2 meters, indoors only". I am really interested in seeing if the R200 will really work outdoors.

Comment: Good question. I find it hard to believe as well, that the R200 says "longer range outdoors" when it seems to be IR based. IR practically always has problems when competing with sunlight.

Answer (score 1):

I only have experience with the kinect, but it will definitely not work outside no matter what (unless the sun is down) and I have had problems when giving demos near large windows with sun.

Tldr near windows or outside during the day is a nogo